# restricting a regression and clustering SE's in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to restrict a regression, only using the datapoints where a variable everevac==1 .. i figured out one way to do it, but am wondering if there's a better way.

In STATA, I would have just run something like this:

```
reg outcome y2006 age black male etc if everevac==1, cluster(persid)
```

I came up with this for R:

```
fit <- ols(formula = outcome[everevac==1] ~ y2006[everevac==1] + 
             age[everevac==1] + black[everevac==1] + 
             male[everevac==1] + hsgrad[everevac==1] + 
             hsgrad[everevac==1] + someco[everevac==1] + 
             ba[everevac==1] + postgrad[everevac==1], x=TRUE, y=TRUE, data = ps2_new)
robcov(fit, cluster = ps2_new$persid[ps2_new$everevac==1])
```

notice that I just restricted all of the variables, to make it var[everevac==1] ..is this even doing what I think it's doing? is there a beter way to do it? i tried using an "if" statement like this:

```
if(everevac==1){ <lm function above, taking out the [everevac==1] on each variable> }
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Add this parameter to the `ols` call, then do not refer to the cluster id by the external value, but rather by the name that will then be evaluated in the context of the `fit`-object which only has the `subset`-ed data:

```
... , subset = everevac==1)

fit <- ols(formula = outcome ~ y2006 + 
                age + black + 
                male + 
                hsgrad + someco + 
                ba + postgrad,
            x=TRUE, y=TRUE, 
            data = ps2_new, subset = everevac==1)
robcov(fit, cluster = persid)
```

BTW, it is considered courteous to include `library(rms)` in the code block.

Answer (score 0):

Simply indexing the dataframe should be sufficient

```
fit <- ols(formula = outcome ~ y2006 + age + black + male + hsgrad + 
             hsgrad + someco + ba + postgrad, x=TRUE, y=TRUE, 
             data = ps2_new[ps2_new$everevac==1,])
```

Comment: By the way, you have hsgrad twice in your formula

Comment: i just got this error: "Error in model.frame.default(formula = outcome ~ y2006 + age + black +  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'y2006')" ...restricting individually, i didn't get the error.  also, thanks for the heads up on the hsgrad

Comment: just to be sure: all of those (y2006, age, black etc) are columns in the ps2_new dataframe?

Comment: yeah they are..it's weird, not sure why it's doing that

Comment: It shouldn't... For instance, try this: `a<-1:10; b<-2*a+rnorm(10,0,0.1); df<-data.frame(a,b); model<-lm(a~b, df[1:5,])`

Comment: It _should_ have been: data = ps2_new[ps2_new$everevac==1, ], but I think the subset method is cleaner.

Comment: @DWin: now I feel stupid... :P corrected the code. PS: did not know the subset parameter, definitely that is cleaner!